# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required (Flask json.dumps)

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-requests, python-docx

I have a form that will redirect to another route to generate a report from docx template after submitting the form. However there's an error (which I suspect is my json issue, I will break it down in details down there)

The **route for chargeback-form**

```
@app.route('/chargeback-form', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chargeback_form():

    form = ChargebackForm()

    if request.method == 'POST': #this block is only entered when the form is submitted

        return redirect(url_for('render_cb_form'), code=307)


    return render_template('chargeback_form.html', form=form)
```

The **route for render-cb-form** after submitting the form

```
@app.route('/render-cb-form', methods=['POST','GET'])
def render_cb_form():

    final_result = json.dumps(request.form)

    template = 'chargeback_template.docx'
    document = from_template(template, final_result)
    document.seek(0)

    return send_file(
        document, mimetype='application/vnd.openxmlformats-'
        'officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', as_attachment=True,
        attachment_filename='generated_chargeback_form.docx')
```

This is my **from_template function**

```
def from_template(template, json_result):
    target_file = StringIO()

    template = DocxTemplate(template)
    context = json_result  # gets the json result used to render the document

    target_file = BytesIO()
    template.render(context)
    template.save(target_file)

    return target_file
```

The Errors in my cmd

```
[2020-03-09 12:31:51,463] ERROR in app: Exception on /render-cb-form [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ad0334\desktop\boost\debugging_env\debug_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\ad0334\desktop\boost\debugging_env\debug_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "c:\users\ad0334\desktop\boost\debugging_env\debug_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "c:\users\ad0334\desktop\boost\debugging_env\debug_env\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\ad0334\desktop\boost\debugging_env\debug_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "c:\users\ad0334\desktop\boost\debugging_env\debug_env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\AD0334\Desktop\Boost\debugging_env\app\routes.py", line 69, in render_cb_form
    document = from_template(template, final_result)
  File "C:\Users\AD0334\Desktop\Boost\debugging_env\app\generate_docx.py", line 21, in from_template
    template.render(context)
  File "c:\users\ad0334\desktop\boost\debugging_env\debug_env\lib\site-packages\docxtpl\__init__.py", line 266, in render
    xml_src = self.build_xml(context, jinja_env)
  File "c:\users\ad0334\desktop\boost\debugging_env\debug_env\lib\site-packages\docxtpl\__init__.py", line 229, in build_xml
    xml = self.render_xml(xml, context, jinja_env)
  File "c:\users\ad0334\desktop\boost\debugging_env\debug_env\lib\site-packages\docxtpl\__init__.py", line 211, in render_xml
    dst_xml = template.render(context)
  File "c:\users\ad0334\desktop\boost\debugging_env\debug_env\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1086, in render
    vars = dict(*args, **kwargs)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2020 12:31:51] "[35m[1mPOST /render-cb-form HTTP/1.1[0m" 500 -
```

When I'm trying to find out the issue, I tried to print my "final_result" in "/render-cb-form":

```
{"csrf_token": "blablabla.blabbla", "cb_ref_no": "cb01201", "cb_date": "1/1/20", "received_date": "20/4/20", "type_card_no": "ABC XXXX 1234", "reason": "scam", "tranx_date": "17/6/20", "amount": "RM567.89"}
```

When I just hard-coded the dict into my function, the docx generator works fine, but when I'm trying to pass as json, the ValueError pops up. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the error lies in this line of code:

```
final_result = json.dumps(request.form)
```

Apparently json.dumps return the result as a **string**, need to add another line of code beneath the "final_result":

```
final_result = json.loads(final_result)
```

which transform the string back to JSON. Anyway, if there's a more efficient way to write the code above, kindly please enlighten me! Thank you in advance :)